# Why this c++ code doesn't compile?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm using Visual studio 2012 and i get a lot of xmemory0 errors.
It's a generic tree implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<class T> class Tree {
public:
    Tree();
    Tree(const T& pNode);
    virtual ~Tree();

    const T& getNode();
    void setNode(const T& pNode);

    void addChild(const Tree<T>& pChild);
    const Tree<T>& getChild(int pIndex);

    const std::list<Tree<T>>* getChildren();
    void printTree(const Tree<T>& pTree, int pLevel=0);
private:
    T node;
    std::list<Tree<T>&>* children;
};

template<class T> Tree<T>::Tree(const T& pNode) : node(pNode), children(nullptr) {
}

template<class T> Tree<T>::Tree() : node(T()), children(nullptr) {
}

template<class T> Tree<T>::~Tree() {
    delete children;
}

template<class T> const T& Tree<T>::getNode() {
    return this->node;
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::setNode(const T& pNode) {
    this->node=pNode;
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::addChild(const Tree<T>& pChild) {
    if(this->children==nullptr) {
        this->children=new std::list<Tree<T>&>();
    }

    this->children->push_back(pChild);
}

template<class T> const Tree<T>& Tree<T>::getChild(int pIndex) {
    if(true) {
    }

    return this->children[pIndex];
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::printTree(const Tree<T>& pTree, int pLevel=0) {
    for(int i=0; i<pLevel; i++) {
        std::cout << "  "; // Print 2 spaces for each level
    }

    std::cout << pTree.node << std::endl;

    if(pTree.children!=nullptr) {
        for(std::list<Tree<T>>::iterator i=pTree.children->begin(); i!=pTree.children->end(); i++) {
            printTree(*i, pLevel+1);
        }
    }
}

template<class T> const std::list<Tree<T>>* Tree<T>::getChildren() {
    return this->children;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Tree<int> a, b,c;

    a.setNode(1);
    b.setNode(2);
    c.setNode(3);

    b.addChild(c);
    a.addChild(b);


    a.printTree(a);
}
```

This is the errors i get (i'm sorry they are in italian language):

```
Errore  1   error C2528: 'pointer': puntatore a riferimento non valido  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    527 1   Translator

Errore  2   error C2528: 'const_pointer': puntatore a riferimento non valido    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    528 1   Translator

Errore  3   error C2535: 'Tree<T> &(*std::allocator<_Ty>::address(Tree<T> &) throw() const)': funzione membro già definita o dichiarata c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    561 1   Translator

Errore  4   error C2528: '_Ptr': puntatore a riferimento non valido c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    599 1   Translator

Errore  5   error C2528: '_Ptr': puntatore a riferimento non valido c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    604 1   Translator

Errore  6   error C2528: 'pointer': puntatore a riferimento non valido  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    700 1   Translator

Errore  7   error C2528: 'const_pointer': puntatore a riferimento non valido    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    701 1    Translator

Errore  8   error C2535: 'Tree<T> &(*std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::address(Tree<T> &) const)': funzione membro già definita o dichiarata    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0 824 1   Translator

Errore  9   error C2528: '_Ptr': puntatore a riferimento non valido c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    890 1   Translator

Errore  10  error C2528: 'abstract declarator': puntatore a riferimento non valido  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    105 1   Translator

Errore  11  error C2528: 'abstract declarator': puntatore a riferimento non valido  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    107 1   Translator

Errore  12  error C2528: 'pointer': puntatore a riferimento non valido  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    122 1   Translator

Errore  13  error C2528: 'const_pointer': puntatore a riferimento non valido    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
11.0\vc\include\xmemory0    123 1   Translator

Errore  14  error C2535: 'void std::list<_Ty>::push_front(_Ty)': funzione membro già definita o dichiarata  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\list 1276    1   Translator

Errore  15  error C2535: 'void std::list<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty)': funzione membro già definita o dichiarata   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\list 1286    1   Translator

Errore  16  error C2535: 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist> std::list<_Ty>::insert(std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>,_Ty)': funzione membro già definita o dichiarata   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\list 1319    1   Translator

Errore  17  error C2664: 'std::list<_Ty>::push_back': impossibile convertire il parametro 1 da 'const Tree<T>' a 'Tree<T> ' c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\translator\translator\main.cpp    46  1   Translator

Errore  18  error C2440: 'inizializzazione': impossibile convertire da 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' a 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'  c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\translator\translator\main.cpp    64  1   Translator

Errore  19  error C2678: '!=' binario: non è stato trovato alcun operatore che accetti un operando sinistro di tipo 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'. È anche possibile che non vi siano conversioni accettabili. c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\translator\translator\main.cpp    64  1   Translator
```

According to Mike Seymour's answer i changed my code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<class T> class Tree {
public:
    Tree();
    Tree(const T& pNode);
    virtual ~Tree();

    const T& getNode();
    void setNode(const T& pNode);

    void addChild(const Tree<T>* pChild);
    const Tree<T>* getChild(int pIndex);

    const std::list<Tree<T>*>* getChildren();
    void printTree(const Tree<T>* pTree, int pLevel=0);
private:
    T node;
    std::list<Tree<T>*>* children;
};

template<class T> Tree<T>::Tree(const T& pNode) : node(pNode), children(nullptr) {
}

template<class T> Tree<T>::Tree() : node(T()), children(nullptr) {
}

template<class T> Tree<T>::~Tree() {
    delete children;
}

template<class T> const T& Tree<T>::getNode() {
    return this->node;
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::setNode(const T& pNode) {
    this->node=pNode;
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::addChild(const Tree<T>* pChild) {
    if(this->children==nullptr) {
        this->children=new std::list<Tree<T>*>();
    }

    this->children->push_back(*pChild);
}

template<class T> const Tree<T>* Tree<T>::getChild(int pIndex) {
    if(true) {
    }

    return this->children[pIndex];
}

template<class T> void Tree<T>::printTree(const Tree<T>* pTree, int pLevel=0) {
    for(int i=0; i<pLevel; i++) {
        std::cout << "  "; // Print 2 spaces for each level
    }

    std::cout << pTree->node << std::endl;

    if(pTree->children!=nullptr) {
        for(std::list<Tree<T>*>::iterator i=pTree->children->begin(); i!=pTree->children->end(); i++) {
            printTree(*i, pLevel+1);
        }
    }
}

template<class T> const std::list<Tree<T>*>* Tree<T>::getChildren() {
    return this->children;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Tree<int> a, b,c;

    a.setNode(1);
    b.setNode(2);
    c.setNode(3);

    a.addChild(&b);
    b.addChild(&c);

    a.printTree(&a);
}
```

but i get this error:

Error   1   error C2664: 'void std::list<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)': cannot convert parameter 1 from const Tree' to 'Tree &&' on line 46

Comment: Why don't you post the code here?

Comment: Please post your code. Also consider posting in CodeReview

Comment: If you want help you need to provide us with the errors you are getting.

Comment: Here is why not: https://ideone.com/r21oQi

Comment: Sorry guys this is my first question on stackoverflow, i get a lot of error C2528 on a file called xmemory0

Comment: @gartenriese CoreReview is only for improving code which *works.* This question would be off-topic there.

Comment: Have you seen the compilation errors? there are hundred of "simple" error and you can debug them easily

Comment: @WileTheCoyot 1. Edit the question instead of putting errors in comments; 2. Copy the *whole* error messages; 3. Put the source code in the question instead of link to pastebin.

Comment: Side Node: Install an English version of your programming environment - it will ease the search for errors in the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::list<Tree<T>&>* children;
```

Standard containers can't store reference types. From the rest of the code, it looks like this should store `Tree<T>` objects. (If you wanted to refer to objects that live somewhere else, you'd have to store pointers rather than references; but this doesn't seem to be the case here).

You also have a duplicate default argument on both the declaration and definition of `printTree`, and a missing `typename` where you declare `std::list<Tree<T>>::iterator i` in `printTree`; it's possible that your compiler will accept these errors though.

Comment: i added the reference so if i call b.addChild(c) after a.addChild(b) i  can get a root (a) with a children (b) which has a child (c)

Comment: Have a look at https://ideone.com/r21oQi to complete your answer

Comment: @DieterLücking: I'm not quite sure what you mean. All those errors are caused by the three problems I've described. The code compiles if I fix them: https://ideone.com/lwRWn9

Comment: @MikeSeymour i need to keep track of changes on the list elements, this is why is used references (and thanks to your answer now i'm using pointers)